# Trying to insert a field from one table into another

Tags: sql, sql-server

So my main table is TableA (Fields: CustomerID, A2, A3, A4, A5), which contains all but one of the fields... 
I need to add TableB's TransactionID field to TableA, so it will looks like: TransactionID, CustomerID, A2, A3, A4, A5.

Table A and Table B are able to link together When the CustomerID.

```
SELECT 
b.TransactionID, a.CustomerID, a.2, a.3, a.4, a.5
FROM TableB b
JOIN TableA a
    ON a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID
```

That query gets everything I need. However, I'm having trouble when it comes to inserting the TransactionID field into TableA. I know I'm missing something obvious.

Thanks.

*Additional information: The issue is TableB doesn't contain the TransactionID field. Every CustomerID contains at least 1 TransactionID, but my goal is to get the TransactionID added to TableB. The common denominator between TableA and TableB is the CustomerID.*

Comment: does TableA  have a field `TransactionID` and you are trying to update that field with the value from TableB?

Comment: what is the error you getting while inserting ?

Comment: Whats the trouble?  Are you getting an error or something else?  Can you show your insert statement that you have tried?

Comment: although I am not really sure why you need it in `TableA` if you can always get it from `TableB` as in your query above

Comment: @isaace The issue is TableB doesn't contain the TransactionID field. Every CustomerID contains at least 1 TransactionID, but my goal is to get the TransactionID added to TableB. The common denominator between TableA and TableB is the CustomerID.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the field to TableA.  [Here is the documentation for how to do that in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).  After that, you use an `Update` statement similar to the `Select` in your initial post.

Answer (score 0):

not sure about data type of transactionID, but it should be something like:

```
ALTER TABLE TableA
ADD TransactionID varchar(30);


UPDATE  a
SET a.TransactionID = b.TransactionID
FROM TableA a
JOIN TableB b
    ON a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to first add a column to `TableA`. This is the syntax

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD column_name datatype;
```

And then you can run this query to import the data from TableB to your new column in TableA

```
UPDATE a 
SET a.TransactionID  = b.TransactionID
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b ON a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID
```